# Flex & space-around are intersecting the content

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container that's scrolling horizionally with checkboxes in it. When a box is checked, a text apears. I want to keep the functionality of the items growing from both sides. The thing is that when some checkboxes are checked, the first one is hidden and you cannot scroll to it:

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

input:checked~label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1"></input>
    <label for="1">1111111111111111111111111</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1"></input>
    <label for="2">22222222222222222222222222222222222</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1"></input>
    <label for="3">333333333333333333333333333333</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to keep the transition coming from the center, but still let the user scrolling all the way to the start and the end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh!!

That's a good one..

It took months from me to solve before.

It's very easy and tricky bro.

Just make your `justify-content: flex-start;` and then add this `flex-grow: 1;` for your children which are `.item` which will seams like a `space-around` effect.

That's the code:

```css
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex; align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: flex-start;     /* ••• this one ••• */
}
.item {
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    height: 40px; text-align: center;
      display: flex; justify-content: center;
      flex-grow: 1;                    /* ••• and this one ••• */
}
label { font-size: 0; transition: 0.5s ease; }
input:checked~label { font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="1"></input>
        <label for="1">1111111111111111111111111</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="2"></input>
        <label for="2">22222222222222222222222222222222222</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="3"></input>
        <label for="3">333333333333333333333333333333</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just done by 2 actions:

1. Remove the `justify-content: space-around;` from your `.container`
2. Add `margin:auto;` to your `.item`.

*(Pay attention, `className` got replaced by `class`, as the CSS does not recognize the className)*

### DEMO

```css
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  /*justify-content: space-around;*/
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
}

label {
  font-size: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

input:checked~label {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <label for="1">1111111111111111111111111</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <label for="2">22222222222222222222222222222222222</label>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" />
    <label for="3">333333333333333333333333333333</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

justify-content: space-around; from the container and use justify-content: space-between; instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes the items only grow to the right.